# Garbage Collection misunderstanding in c#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

i have searched on google not getting what i want. i don't know i am right or wrong. 
look , i have trying to understand GC.Collect() so here is the code..

```
public class SomePublisher
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}

public class SomeSubscriber
{
    public static int Count;

    public SomeSubscriber(SomePublisher publisher)
    {
        publisher.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(publisher_SomeEvent);
    }

    ~SomeSubscriber()
    {
        SomeSubscriber.Count++;
    }

    private void publisher_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: something
    }
}
```

i do this in my main thread..

```
 SomePublisher publisher = new SomePublisher();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SomeSubscriber subscriber = new SomeSubscriber(publisher);
            subscriber = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine(SomeSubscriber.Count.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

i am getting output 0 but it should bebe 10 according to me because GC.Collect() must have remove class1 objects from memory so class1 destructor must be called so the count must be increased to 10..can any body explain this..

Comment: The main thing to understand about `GC.Collect();` is that you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Are you testing it in debug mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note also that C# does not have destructors<sup>1</sup>, it has finalizers.  These are very different things, and you should not confuse them.)

The "problem" is on this line:

```
publisher.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(publisher_SomeEvent);
```

This creates a delegate targeting the `publisher_SomeEvent()` method of the particular object instance, and adds this delegate to the invocation list for the `publisher.SomeEvent` event.  This delegate object references the target object, and it is preventing the object from being collected!  (This is a good thing -- if you take a delegate to a method on a particular object then you don't want that object being collected until the delegate is no longer referenced.)

This technically isn't a problem at all, but rather is the runtime keeping objects alive that are still referenced.

To illustrate, this is the chain of references:

```
SomePublisher -+-> EventHandler --> SomeSubscriber
               |
               +-> EventHandler --> SomeSubscriber
               |
               +-> (Eight more...)
```

You need to do one of two things before calling `GC.Collect()`:

1. Unsubscribe from the event before releasing each `SomePublisher` object.  This will make both the `EventHandler` delegate instances and the `SomeSubscriber` instances they reference eligible for collection.
2. Set `publisher = null;`.  This will cause the entire object graph to become eligible for collection.

In both cases, this will release all references to the `SomeSubscriber` objects.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the C# specification does call these blocks of code "destructors," but this is a horrible name.  Those familiar with garbage-collected languages will be confused by it, as "finalizer" is the widespread term for code that is invoked by the garbage collector when an object is no longer reachable.  C++ developers in particular will expect the destructor to be executed at a different time.  So yes, C# has something called a "destructor," but it is not a destructor.  (Saying something doesn't make it so!)

Comment: i have already used this GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); still getting 0.

Comment: [It seems to work for me.](http://ideone.com/wARKwW)  If you are still having trouble then please post your complete code sample.  Or better yet, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) -- something short I can copy and paste to see exactly the same behavior.  In the process of creating an SSCCE you may well solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Technically, C# does have "destructors"; the term refers to the block of code following `~className`.  Declaring a destructor causes C# to auto-generate a `Finalize` override which wraps the supplied code in a try/finally block along with a call to `base.Finalize()`.  The term "finalizer" accurately describes the generated method, but "destructor" is the correct term for the user-supplied portion.  I think "destructor" is a lousy name, but I know of no other common term to refer *just* to the user-supplied code.

Comment: @supercat Between "destructor" and "finalizer" I choose to call them the latter.  While it's a tad inaccurate, it's a whole bunch more accurate than the former term, which implies something completely different.  The simple fact is that the C# spec uses a terrible and confusing term for these blocks of code.

Comment: @cdhowie: In most contexts the terms may be used interchangeably, and when they are interchangeable I prefer the term "finalizer".  My point is that there are terms for which the term "destructor", though horrible, is appropriate and no other term is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The finalizers of SomeSubcriber objects will not be called till end. Because even though SomeSubscriber objects are set to null, its memory is still being referenced by the event SomeEvent of SomePublisher object, which is alive till the end of application. Thus when GC.Collect() is called, garbage collector won’t find any objects to put in finalizer queue.

```
public SomeSubscriber(SomePublisher publisher)
{
// publisher.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(publisher_SomeEvent);
}
```

If we can replace the constructor of SomeSubcriber by the code above, then we will get the result as 10 in console.